# Can I make an ASP.NET Core controller internal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

ASP.NET (and Core) controllers need to be `public`.

Problem is I have a controller which depends (in its constructor) on something `internal`. And that dependency depends on something internal, which depends on something internal, etc. So I need to make the controller `internal` as well.

But then it won't be discovered by the controller factory.

Is there a way to make an `internal` controller discoverable?

Comment: Can you post this dependency you're saying? Public is higher than internal, It wouldn't really matter if the dependency was internal. Unless it was in the constructor

Comment: @DevEstacion Yes, in the constructor.

Comment: Then dont inject it as a parameter, instantiate it on the contructor declaration or provide a method to use it.

Comment: @DevEstacion Not possible in my case, it's supposed to get in there via contructor injection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sou you have this (it always helps to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question):

```
internal class FooDependency
{

}

public class FooController
{
    public FooController(FooDependency dependency)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And you can't make `FooDependency` public, but you need `FooController` to be public?

Then you need to apply a public interface to the internal dependencies:

```
public interface IFooDependency
{

}

internal class FooDependency : IFooDependency
{

}

public class FooController
{
    public FooController(IFooDependency dependency)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't always suit the design, though in my case it does, thanks. It would be best to be able to configure the controller factory to find a particular internal controller, but I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: Still bleeds/forces a public type. No reason why interfaces need to be public :|

Answer (score 24):

If you want to include internal controllers, you can provide your own implementation of the `ControllerFeatureProvider` class which is responsible for determining whether a type is a controller or not. In the following example I have created an implementation that looks for controllers implementing a custom base class and falling back to the default implementation for all other cases. In this case, the custom controllers will be discoverable despite being internal, while all other controllers will not.

```
class CustomControllerFeatureProvider : ControllerFeatureProvider
{
    protected override bool IsController(TypeInfo typeInfo)
    {
        var isCustomController = !typeInfo.IsAbstract && typeof(MyCustomControllerBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo);
        return isCustomController || base.IsController(typeInfo);
    }
}
```

and to register it:

```
services.AddMvc().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
{
    manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new CustomControllerFeatureProvider());
});
```

You should probably take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/ControllerFeatureProvider.cs#L41) of `IsController` to see how ASP.NET handles edge cases around the types.

Comment: Ty, that's a perfect solution. The only thing I want to mention that if you use `services.AddControllers()` instead of `services.AddMvc()` - that's fine too.