# Controller constructor does not get called

Tags: http, asp.net-core, routes

Hello i am trying to understand why do my requests not enter my api route.They seem to reach the server but they wont fan out in the `MVC`.

The server is running on: `http://localhost:9300`
The route  i am requesting is : `http://localhost:9300/api/getusers`
**Program**

```cs
public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) {
            var builder = new WebHostBuilder();
            builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            var url = Address.Default.ToUrl();
            builder.UseKestrel().UseUrls(url);
            return builder;

        }

    }
```

**Startup**

```cs
public class Startup {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddMvc();
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration;
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {

            Debug.WriteLine("Entered server"); //enters successfully here
            app.UseMvc(); //does not enter the controller
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

This is a simple controller with a `GET` method.The constructor is not invoked at all.Why would this happen?I know it when the server runs the first time ..it does a health check on its routes.

```cs
[ApiController]
    class UserController : ControllerBase {

        private static List<User> users = new List<User> {
                new User{Id=0,Age=0,Name="Failed"},
                new User{Id=12,Age=33,Name="Daniel"},
                new User{Id=13,Age=33,Name="Marian"},
            };

        public UserController() {
            Debug.WriteLine("Controller called"); //does not get called !
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/getusers")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetUsers() {

            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return new HttpResponseMessage {
                Content = new StringContent(users.ToJson()),
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
            };
        }
}
```

**P.S** Do i have to add anyything ? What am i missing i followed other implementations closely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created the webapi project using `dotnet new webapi`.
I've managed to get to the url with the similar configuration by changing the access modifier of a similar controller. Try to add `public` keyword to the `class UserController`. So it should be `public class UserController`

I will provide more information about the configuration of the project if it is necessary and the step above does not help.

Comment: Does it matter if the controller `class` is public or not ?

Comment: According to the `IsController`'s [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/ControllerFeatureProvider.cs#L41), yes. However, you can try to adjust [the proposed workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50906593/4880379) if you have the reason to not make it public.