# ASP.NET (Core)'s zombie virus of 'public': can controllers be internal?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, scope

The context is ASP.NET Core.

Please consider the following minimal setup.

```
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
   public ExampleController(IExempleService exampleService)
   {

(...)

public interface IExampleService
{
   ExampleStruct Foo();
}

public readonly struct ExampleStruct (...)
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IInverterService, InverterService>();
```

There is a chain of publicity here.

1. The controller must be public; to be discoverable. *Fair.*
2. The controller's constructor must be public; for the framework to instantiate it. *That's life.*
3. The service interface must be public because the controller's constructor is public. *Sadness.*
4. The service types (e.g. ExampleStruct) must be `public` because the interface is public. *I feel sick.*

There are practical consequences of this:

- Documentation, I'm documenting practically internal but technically public classes with senseless comments that will become outdated.
- Public types have more responsibilities. For example, an internal struct needs not to provide equality, but when it's public it should.

I suppose there are two questions here:

- Would there eventually be a structural solution for this zombie virus of public access?
- Am I doing it wrong and there is an OK solution now?

---

Unit testing and `internal` go together with [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-5.0) .

Comment: You ***can*** make your controllers internal, you will just have to make them discoverable with `ControllerFeatureProvider` take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50906593/1612975

Comment: @MichaelRandall That's very interesting. I'm not OP but thank you for the link! :)

Comment: @MichaelRandall Could you please make your comment an answer and I''ll add the my setup `MyControllerFeatureProvider`. Or if you prefer just make a short answer and I'll post my answer alongside and accept your answer. 
I'd like the credit to go to you, rather than me posting an answer and marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***can*** make your *controllers* `internal`, you will just have to make them *discoverable* with [`ControllerFeatureProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controllerfeatureprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

> Discovers controllers from a list of `ApplicationPart` instances.

There are 4 types of way define controllers in Asp.Net Core:

1. Inherit from ControllerBase class
2. Define a controller with a Name that Contains "Controller" suffix.
3. Define With Controller Attribute
4. Define Custom Controller Type Class

Of most importance to your situation of an `internal` controller, would be the last point (Define Custom Controller Type).

To do this you will need to

- Implement a `ControllerFeatureProvider`
- override `IsController` and implement any logic for the discoverability of your type

E.g.

```
internal class MyControllerFeatureProvider : ControllerFeatureProvider
{
    protected override bool IsController(TypeInfo typeInfo)
    {
        ...
```

- Add it to the `ConfigureApplicationPartManager` via the `FeatureProviders`

E.g.

```
.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
{
    manager.FeatureProviders.Add(YourControllerFeatureProvider)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

*All credit should go to @MichaelRandall:*

> You *can* make your controllers internal, you will just have to make them discoverable with ControllerFeatureProvider take a look at this stackoverflow.com/a/50906593/1612975 – Michael Randall

---

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    (...)
    services
        .AddControllers(options => ...)
        .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
        {
            manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new MyControllerFeatureProvider());
        })
     
(...)   

internal class MyControllerFeatureProvider : ControllerFeatureProvider
{
    protected override bool IsController(TypeInfo typeInfo)
    {
        // https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/ControllerFeatureProvider.cs,41
        // contains
        // 
        // // We only consider public top-level classes as controllers. IsPublic returns false for nested
        // // classes, regardless of visibility modifiers
        // if (!typeInfo.IsPublic)
        // {
        //   return false;
        // }

        if (typeInfo.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            typeInfo.IsDefined(typeof(ApiControllerAttribute)))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Found controller '{typeInfo.Name}'");
            return true;
        }

        if (typeInfo.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail($"Found class that ends in 'Controller' but will not be registered as a controller: {typeInfo.Name}");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```